# Computing pairwise intersections for a huge folder of files

Tags: database, file, compression, comparison

I have a folder of ~1500 heavily compressed files, each containing 20-30 million integers. I want to compute a 2-dimensional array A[x][y], where x and y are filenames, such that A[x][y] equals the count of integers contained in both file 'x' and file 'y'. For example if 'x' contains 1,2,3 and 'y' contains 2,3,4,5,6 then A[x][y] = 2.

In practice this means I have to do millions of comparisons between the files. However, loading the files (which are heavily compressed) to memory takes a few seconds, and I only have 16GB RAM whereas the folder is of size ~150GB so it seems I  have to constantly load and unload them, which of course takes a very long time.

Does anyone have any suggestions for tackling this problem? I work with Python, so references to libraries, etc., would be appreciated.

Comment: What your "A[x][y]" is is not at all clear. If x has 19 integers in it and y has 23 integers in it, what is A[x][y]? Is that element the pair {19,23}? The integer 42? What do comparisons have to do with it? A 1500x1500 array of integers or pairs of integers is not large, 10 to 20 megabytes maybe. What's the problem? If you want to find pairs of files with the _same_ number of integers, you don't need a matrix. Just the list of ~1500 file names and counts. Then sort on the counts in O(n log n) time and look through the list in O(n) time to find all the matches. Takes less than a millisecond.

Comment: @MarkAdler I added clarification.  A[x][y] equals the count of integers contained in both file 'x' and file 'y'. For example if 'x' contains 1,2,3 and 'y' contains 2,3,4,5,6 then A[x][y] = 2. I'm computing the intersection of 'x' and 'y'

Comment: What is the range of possible integers? If you create the union of all of the integers in all of the files, how many integers are in that set?

Comment: @MarkAdler They are all unsigned int64s. If I create a union, I suspect there would something on the order of 10 billion unique integers

Comment: Too many then. I am not aware of a useful algorithm here.